# Proving that $\angle MAC = 30^{\circ}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

> In $\Delta ABC$, $M$ is an interior point such that,
>
> $MB=MA$,
>
> $MC=CB$,
>
> $\angle CBA = 2 \angle BAC$.
>
> Prove that $\angle MAC = 30^\circ$

[image]

I was able to solve this question using trigonometry [here's my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sH7Y.jpg)
I was however unable to find any synthetic solution and require some aid for that.

Comment: What did you try? Did you try to use the hint given (you did not mention it here but there was one in the original problem)?

Comment: sorry i forgot to include my work, ill do that right away. Yes i did try to make use of the hint but couldn't make progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First construct the $\triangle{AMD}\cong\triangle{BMC}$.

Let $\angle CBA = 2x, \angle BAC = x, \angle MAB=\angle MBA=a$

And let the intersection of $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline {BD}$ be $O$

By looking at the diagram below you can easily find that $\angle CAD=x$ and $\angle MAC=x-a$.

As $\triangle{ABD}\cong\triangle{ABC}$ you can find out that quadrilateral $ABCD$ is an isosceles trapezoid a.k.a trapezoid inscribed in a circle

Then you can easily find $\angle ACD = x$ and $AD=DC=MD=MC$.

Therefore $\triangle {MCD}$ is equilateral and $\angle CMD=60$.

As The sum of the angles around a single point is equal to 360 degrees you get   $\angle CMD=180-4x+4a$

By both of the above equations you get,

$180-4x+4a=60$

By simplifying, $x-a=30=\angle MAC$

[image]

*Sorry for my bad handwriting if you need any further clarification please ask in the comments.

Thank you for sharing such an amazing problem.

Comment: So the crux move was to construct the point D and then everything falls into place. Very nice solution! Also in the second paragraph it should be $\Delta ABD \cong \Delta BAC$